# regex caret ampersand works but don't know why

Tags: java, regex, validation, xss

I want to prevent inputting some special characters `" < >`  in my spring mvc project.

```
    @Pattern(regexp="[^&]")
```

It works exactly fine but I don't know why. (I am still finding good reference for regex)

Comment: Give us an example of input and output.

Comment: That RegEx should match anything that isn't an `&` character.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't work exactly fine.

Comment: So, you guys say there is no other meaning in the &, right? Then I cannot use the expression. But... but.... but.... It does not allow < > " . I tested it again and again.... I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

**Negated Character Class**

- `[^&]` is a negated character class that matches **one** character that is not `&` (the `^` is what makes is negative)
- To only a string that contains no `<`,`>` or `"`, add them to a negated character class and use anchors:
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Like so:

```
^[^<>"]+$
```

With the `matches` method, you don't need the anchors:

```
if (subjectString.matches("[^<>\"]+")) {
    // It matched!
  } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

> It works exactly fine.

I [doubt](http://regex101.com/r/oZ4zQ2/7) that honestly.. your negated character class matches **any character** except: `&`, if you want to prevent the other characters you specified, add them to your class as well.

```
[^&"<>]   # any character except: '&', '"', '<', '>'
```

If you want to accept the `&` then just remove it from the class.

```
[^"<>]
```

You may also want to use a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) to match multiple occurrences.

Comment: I am not good at regex. But it prevents " , < , > as well. I don't know why. Try it.

Comment: It prevents those characters because you stated you wanted to prevent them.

Comment: sorry. it was my mistake.